# pdf to png conversion of latex generated plot

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, gimp, inkscape, converters

I have a bunch of pdf (plots generated using pgf in pdflatex) files that I would like to convert to png files. So far I've tried the following:

1) ImageMagick

```
convert -density 500 a.pdf -quality 90 a.png
```

it works, but shapes (symbols) in my plot are not completely filled. Quality is good though.
2) Poppler

```
pdftoppm a.pdf b.png
```

Good quality, shapes are all completely filled, but font is exchanged. So not useful for my purpose.

3) Inkscape

```
inkscape a.pdf -z --export-dpi=500 --export-area-drawing --export-png=a.png
```

is also working, but font is changed.

4) Gimp

does exactly what I want, but I found no way of specifying the dpi on

```
file-pdf-load
```

so no batch processing possible.

The fonts used are:

name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID

TFVHHB+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0

EWZFDL+CMSY6                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       8  0

WGUATP+CMMI8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0

KIVMKN+CMMI6                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      10  0

Any ideas what software could be used or how one of these options could be working for me?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Might not be able to offer much help without evaluating the PDFs. Try running `pdffonts a.pdf` to list the fonts used.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've added the output now.

Comment: In GIMP, you can use `gimp_image_scale` to resize and scale the content of an image (x and y pixels). As far as I know, it is the same of changing the dpi. So first you load the pdf image with `file-pdf-load` then you can scale it.